# Ubuntu group permission how to change

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, user-accounts

How do I change the permissions for a specific group that I have created?

Say for example I create four new users named Anna, David, Carl and Eva and I also create two different groups which I name technician and normaluser. Now when I have created these groups and users I move Anna to the technician group and David to normaluser.

But here is where I'm stuck, I dont know howto give the technician group 'rwx' or full permissions and give normaluser group 'rx' and the rest should just have 'x'.

I've tried with the command *chgrp {-R} [group] [file|directory]* .. But that kind of messed up my whole system, cause that command changes the group of all the stuff. Also I can't seem to find anything that works with *chown {-R} [user]{:group} [file|directory]*.

Answer (score 0):

**chgrp** will change the group of a file/directory.

then with **chmod** you can change the permissions of that file/directory for the owner, the group and the rest of the world.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to change for every file/directory, but I want to change it so it's permanently for that specific group. So the technicians are practically root, well they should be root if they have rwx on everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a finer granularity of permissions by using Access Control Lists (ACLs):

```
setfacl -m group:technician:rwx,normaluser:rx the_dir
```

Will set the permissions of the different groups to different values.